# Reconfigure an ADO.NET connection when shifting an SSIS package to Azure

Tags: azure, ssis, odbc

We currently have a series of SSIS packages deployed to an on-prem SQL Server instance. We are in the process of shifting all our on-prem stuff into Azure. In Azure, I have configured the SSIS Integration Runtime in Azure Data Factory and have started deploying some existing packages with success.
The issue I am now having is around one of the packages that connects to a MySQL database and copies data over into a Azure SQL database. On our on-prem server we have an ODBC DSN connection defined that users the MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode driver to connect to the MySQL instance. The SSIS package connection is a ADO.NET:System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection type that uses this ODBC DSN connection. This package works fine when deployed to our on-prem server. After attempting to run the same package in Azure I get the following error:

```
ADO NET Source has failed to acquire the connection .... with the following error message:
 "ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified".
```

I know why this is being thrown but is there a good approach to storing these credentials somewhere in Azure and having the package read from them to acquire a connection?

Edit: When deploying to Azure, the packages are being deployed to a Azure SQL database not a Azure SQL managed instance

Comment: Can you use an ADO.NET Source instead of an ODBC source and then configure the credentials with parameters?

Comment: I'll try. Thanks for the suggestion.